# Symfony - Doctrine QueryBuilder produces wrong sql

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to build a query via query builder.

```
$photosQuery = $photoRepository->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->join('AppBundle:User', 'u')
        ->where('LOWER(p.title) LIKE :phrase OR LOWER(u.username) LIKE :phrase AND p.isActive = :isActive AND p.isModerated = :isModerated')
        ->setParameter('phrase', '%'.strtolower($phrase).'%')
        ->setParameter('isActive', true)
        ->setParameter('isModerated', true)
        ->getQuery();
```

It gives me

```
SELECT p0_.id AS id_0,
       p0_.title AS title_1,
       p0_.description AS description_2,
       p0_.name AS name_3,
       p0_.creation_date AS creation_date_4,
       p0_.edit_date AS edit_date_5,
       p0_.is_moderated AS is_moderated_6,
       p0_.moderation_date AS moderation_date_7,
       p0_.is_active AS is_active_8,
       p0_.user_id AS user_id_9,
       p0_.category_id AS category_id_10
FROM photos p0_
INNER JOIN users u1_ ON (LOWER(p0_.title) LIKE ?
                         OR LOWER(u1_.username) LIKE ?
                         AND p0_.is_active = ?
                         AND p0_.is_moderated = ?)
```

Why are my `WHERE` parameters in the join `ON()` portion and not a traditional `WHERE`?

Thank you!

Comment: try changing your join to `->join('p.user', 'u')`

Comment: I added an answer that more specifically explains why this occurred and how you can approach this problem in the future and not make the same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine provides a wrapper around lower-level database connections that to not necessary have all the features present in DQL. As such, it emulates some features (such as named parameters, or splitting array parameters into multiple separate values).

You're seeing that in action here: the named parameters are converted into positional parameters in the raw query. Doctrine still knows what the mapping is, though, and is able to correctly order them when the query and parameters are sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer from jbafford explained some information Doctrine but did not explicitly answer why the `ON` was used instead of the `WHERE`, and it stems from a common mistake (of which I recently made as well).

In your query, when you use

```
->join('AppBundle:User', 'u')
```

you are simply telling the query builder that you need to join on the `User` table, but it doesn't specifically know that you want to join on the `user` association of your `Photo` entity.  You may think - why doesn't this happen automatically?  Well, imagine if you had 2 another association on your table that linked to a `User` entity as well (maybe a *createdBy* field or similar).  In that case Doctrine wouldn't know the association you wanted.

So, instead the proper thing to do is join directly on your association rather than generically on the entity, like so:

```
->join('p.user', 'u')
```

and then Doctrine will handle the rest.  I couldn't actually tell you why it uses the `where()` condition for the join, unless it's just assuming that's what you wanted, since it needs to know how to join on *something*.

So just remember that when you are joining on an association you already defined, join on the association as described in your entities rather than thinking of it in a straight SQL format where you'd join on the table.